# Interpretation of a binary regression plot

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I created an avplot of a linear binary regression. I was wondering how do I interpret the regression residuals in the corner like that?

Would you say it follows a heteroskedastic pattern?

Thanks!

Note: My binary formatting is Sex: Male (0), Female (1),
Employment: Employed (1), unemployed (0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear probability models follow a heteroskedastic pattern by construction. You'll have to use robust standard errors.